# how to get the column or line of a search result in excel?

Tags: excel, vlookup

In *Excel*, when I use a `VLOOKUP` search, the result is the content of a cell which coordinates are the matching row and the passed column (third argument). In my use case, I don't mind the content, I only need the row number of the matching cell for a `VLOOKUP` or the column number for a `HLOOKUP`.

One solution is to include an additional column in the case of a `VLOOKUP`, containing the row number.

Is there something smarter, which don't need an additional column?

Comment: `MATCH`.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly you could use `Match` formula

**Formula:**

`=MATCH(A1,$G$1:$G$5,0)`

**Results:**

[image]